# Is the expression "I am resentful of the god" appropriate?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, culture

When things don't go well as you wished and you feel frustrated, Koreans often use the expression

> I am resentful of the god/sky.

Is this expression used in English? If not, what is the proper expression?

The above translation was suggested by Google translate, and I couldn't understand the meaning of the word "resentful" very well. According to the dictionary, it seems to me that it contains both being angry and unhappy.

But the god is considered to be powerful and a being who grants your wish. It is not good to express your anger to the god. You feel angry but you should not blame the god. Rather, you should make the god feel sorry for you, so that good things happen to you in the future. I want to know the above expression is appropriate in this context.

Comment: That is not an English idiom. Frustrated and angry at how things are going, an English speaker might use an expletive instead.  The choice would depend on the degree of anger and frustration.

Comment: "I am resentful of God/the sky" isn't idiomatic in English, but ["to rage against the heavens"](https://www.google.com/search?q=rage+against+the+heavens) is a phrase for "being angry with fate/existence/God/etc."

Comment: "I am pissed off" works but is impolite. "The fates are against me" is idiomatic and has Greek roots (as in the Fates). In the West, God is a singular, omnipotent being; whereas "the gods" generally pertains to polytheism, as in "the gods must be crazy." "God is out to get me" is an idiomatic expression but doesn't quite fit. But probably the best would be a simple "goddammit!" [God damn it!].

Answer (score 1):

"**Resentful**" means *feeling or expressing bitterness or indignation at having been treated unfairly* ([**Oxford**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resentful)); *feeling angry because you have been forced to accept someone or something that you do not like* ([**Cambridge**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/resentful)).

You think right, it does cover both meanings of anger and unhappiness.

- **I am resentful of God/the heavens.** is understood and a proper, grammatically correct sentence. However, I couldn't find any references of it being used.

A rather accusative expression you might be looking for is:

- "[to rage against the heavens](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rage+against)" which means *to vent one's anger about someone or something; to criticize someone or something severely.*